# Ldap_bind() ERROR

Tags: ldap

Good day! How do we know that a LDAP server allows anonymous connections?

When i run my php program:
i get this error:

Warning: ldap_bind() [function.ldap-bind]: Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in /var/www/sue/ldapTest2.php on line 14

This is my simple sample test program:

LDAP query test";
        echo "Connecting ...";

        $ds=ldap_connect("apserv"); // must be a valid LDAP server!

        echo "Connect result is ".$ds."

";
         if ($ds) {

                echo "Binding ...";
                $r=ldap_bind($ds); // this is an "anonymous" bind, typically

        // read-only access

        }
        echo "Bind result is ".$r."

";

?>

OUTPUTS:

LDAP query test
Connecting ...Connect result is Resource id #2

Binding ...
Warning: ldap_bind() [function.ldap-bind]: Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in /var/www/sue/ldapTest2.php on line 14
Bind result is

Need help.. THANKS.. =)

Answer (score 3):

Is your server up? Verify that it is up by telneting to port 389 first. This looks like a server not running issue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to check whether your specific server supports anonymous binds (1) or are you looking for a generic way to determine if some LDAP server supports anonymous binds (2)?

(1) What server are you testing against? OpenLDAP provides the following configuration settings:

- `disallow bind_anon`: dissallows anonymous binds; enabled by default
- `allow bind_anon_cred`: allows so called unauthenticated binds (username but no password provided); disabled by default
- `disallow bind_simple_unprotected`: disallow simple binds over non-TLS-connections; enabled by default
- `disallow bind_simple`: disallow simple binds completely; enabled by default

So you should check if your server configuration disbales anonymous binds.

(2) A generic way to check for anonymous bind support would be to suppress warnings on `ldap_bind()` and check the result:

```
function isAnonymousBindSupported($ldap)
{
    return @ldap_bind($ldap)
}
```

Your error message

```
Warning: ldap_bind() [function.ldap-bind]: Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in /var/www/sue/ldapTest2.php on line 14
```

though is actually a clear sign that there is some sort of connection problem between the computer running your script and the LDAP server. Connection errors are not reported on a call to `ldap_connect()` as no connection attempt is made prior to calling `ldap_bind()` - all connection errors will therefore be raised on `ldap_bind()`.

Please check the following:

- Is the computer running your script able to resolve the name `apserv` via DNS? You can test this by `ping`ing `apserv` by its name or by running `nslookup`.
- Can you ping the IP address of `apserv`?
- Can you connect to the server using its IP address?
- Is there a firewall that blocks access to port 389 of the target machine?
- Are you able to connect to the LDAP server with some sort of LDAP tool?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fun one!  As far as I understand it, according to the LDAP standard, a bind with a username, but no password counts as an anonymous bind.

So connect with a valid user, but no password, and see if you get connected and access.  If so, it allows Anonymous binds, if not, you should get back something like LDAP -13 confidentiality required.

Comment: That's called an unauthenticated bind and differs somewhat from an anonymous bind.

Comment: True, but a bind with no password, gets rights as if it were an anonymous bind.